# Flutter newbie facing this technical issue when I tried to run my first app

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

while running my first app
This below is the error message when I got when I tried to run an app and even the default app that came with the flutter.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient

Exception: Gradle task assemblebug failed with Exit code 1
```

What I tried:

1. Invalidate caches/restart
2. Try to connect a real device instead of emulator. Came with more errors.
3. Changed compilesdkversion from 28 -29 ( under the build.gradle) also targets diversion from 28-29
4. Confirmed the distributionurl under (gradle-wrapper.properties) is https=//services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
5. The flutter doctor result below.

```
C:\Users\TOPE>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at C:\Users\TOPE\FLUTTER\flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (7 days ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\TOPE\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

6. saw a recommendation to similar issue on GitHub. Which says "This error indicates a failure to download the gradle version specified in your project's gradle wrapper. Try running again with a different/faster internet connection". As result I connected to the internet. First run. It brought out another nasty errors. Second time same error. After that the Android studio was shutting down when I reopen it shuts down at the preparing work space (i.e when am connected to the internet)

Comment: are you connected to the internet ?

Comment: No, I saw a recommendation to similar issue on GitHub. Which saysThis error indicates a failure to download the gradle version specified in your project's gradle wrapper. Try running again with a different/faster internet connection". As result I connected to the internet. First run. It brought out another nasty errors. Second time same error. After that the Android studio was shutting down when I reopen it shuts down at the preparing work space (i.e when am connected to the internet)